# Skipping Columns in Match Search Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to skip columns in a match search? For example...My searched for value appears in multiple different cells within the same row, but I'd only like to search for it within predetermined columns and not the entire row.

[image]

Comment: But what logic is there to indicate which column(s) should not be considered? Is there some flag in another row, for example, which indicates which columns are to be considered and/or not considered?

Comment: If you have Excel 365, use Filter to return only those columns you want to search, then Match on that